# config problems in sendmail

Tags: 12.04, sendmail

I am in the last step of the send mail config, due to some issues the send mail in /usr/sbin/ is not getting accessed even though i gave permissions. I have to perform the following step

```
     /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@domain.com < "My test email being sent from sendmail"
```

Answer (score 0):

sendmail expects email headers before email body on its standard input.

Try the test command below:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- myemail@domain.com <<END
subject: test

My test email being sent from sendmail
END
```

`-i` - do not treat "single dot" line as end of message
`--` - end of command line options (only recipient addresses follow)
`-t` - get recipient addresses from email headers

Comment: It is showing this type of error,
  bash: cd: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Not a directory